# PIC16f877a USART Interrupt handling

Tags: interrupt-handling

I am trying to write a simple code to receive and resend data using usart but the code is not working. Can someone give suggestions on the possible flaws in the code.Please note that I am using USART at baud rate 9600 with clock frequency 4MHz.

```js
#include<pic.h>
void main()
{   TRISB=0X00;
    TXEN=1;
    SYNC=0;
    BRGH=1;
    SPEN=1;
    CREN=1;
   //RCEN=1;
    SPBRG=0X19;
    INTCON=0X80;
    TRISC7=1;
    TRISC6=0;
    RCIE=1;
    TXIE=1;
    while(1);
}

void interrupt rectrans()
{
    if(RCIF==1)
    {
     TXREG=RCREG;
     while(!TRMT);
     RCIF=0;
    }
    else if(TXIF==1)
    {TXIF=0;
    }
}
```

Comment: is my concept of interrupt handling correct?

Comment: Try the http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

I think you should enable GIE bit or Global Interrupt[image] Enable bit for activating any interrupt as you can see from the attached diagram with this answer.. Try to add GIE=1; to enable global interrupt... You can see and AND gate to which GIE bit is connected only all any other interrupt will pass if GIE bit is high